# How to write that I used a graphic from another source and modified it?

Tags: word-choice, formality

I'm writing a thesis in English (I'm from Germany) in which I'll use a graphic from a book that I modified just a little bit. How do write it correctly?

> - see [source], slightly modified.
> - slightly modified from [source].

Comment: I think this is more of a writing question than an English language one, but I'm not sure if it would belong on Writers SE.  Anyway, the second example seems more appropriate than the first, but still might not fit depending on where you're using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I do so in a research paper I write "adapted from [source]".

Comment: Okay, that sounds good, but what a 'value' has adopted? E.g. I just changed some spelling, than my modification is on a very low level. But when I change more, which may lead to a new definition?

Comment: @area404: If the actual amount of modification (*adaptation*, not *adoption*) is important, you should probably include both the original *and* your amended version. But in that case you'd need to think carefully about *why* you're including the graphic in the first place, and/or why you need to modify it at all.

Comment: In this specific case I modified it to fit on one page, so the meaning is the same

Answer (score 0):

I would use a footnote. At the bottom of the page, I would explain briefly that although I have modificated the graphic, it was taken from: (cite source).

I'm Spanish but I always work using English. I have never written a thesis, though.